# Create object with contructor based on enum flag

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'd like to create an object based on enum flag.

Here's the sample code:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var workflowBasic = new WorkflowBasic(WorkflowFlag.One);

        if (workflowBasic.Flag == WorkflowFlag.One)
        {
            // create WorkflowOne workflow 
        }
        else if (workflowBasic.Flag == WorkflowFlag.Two)
        {
            // create WorkflowTwo workflow
        }

        // TODO: rest action on created variable
    }
}

public class WorkflowOne
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public WorkflowOne(int count)
    {
        Count = count;
    }
}

public class WorkflowTwo
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public WorkflowTwo(int count)
    {
        Count = count;
    }
}

public class WorkflowBasic
{
    public WorkflowFlag Flag { get; set; }

    public WorkflowBasic(WorkflowFlag flag)
    {
        Flag = flag;
    }
}

public enum WorkflowFlag
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
}
```

So for WorkflowFlag.One it should creates WorkflowOne object and for WorkflowFlag.Two it should create WorkflowTwo.

Moreover, I'd like to create only one variable so I do not want to create some kind of:

```
    if (workflowBasic.Flag == WorkflowFlag.One)
    {
        var objectTest = new WorkflowOne(1);
    }
    else if (workflowBasic.Flag == WorkflowFlag.Two)
    {
        var objectTest = new WorkflowTwo(2);
    }
```

If it is something unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirement you are describing is a known as an ["abstract factory" design pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).You would give the enum to the abstract factory, and it would return you the relevant workflow object.

You might find that your workflow is a case of the ["strategy" design pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). I'd suggest they should all implement a common interface.

There are lots of ways of implementing this. One example would be to create an attribute which has the enum value as a parameter. Attach this attribute to each of your workflow classes with the relevant enum. The abstract factory can then use reflection to find the class which implements the workflow interface and also has the attribute with the required enum value.

And I would suggest adding unit tests to ensure that there is an implementation of each enum value.